# What architecture to use for Apple M1 docker image: arm/v5, arm/v7, arm64/v8?

Tags: macos, docker, apple-m1

I want to build my docker image for the new Apple M1 CPU. I went to see architecture in [one of  official docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated) and I see the following ARM architectures listed:

```
linux/arm/v5
linux/arm/v7
linux/arm64/v8
```

What's the difference and which one should I use?

Comment: I believe you want arm64/8 as per https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/ also this question would be probably better to ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com) as it doesn't have anything to do with programming...

Answer (score 9):

M1 / Apple Silicon uses the `linux/arm64/v8` architecture. Docker will show a warning when running a non-native image:

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

Answer (score 1):

linux/arm64 seems to be working just fine